# How do I self terminate an EC2 with one command?

Tags: amazon-web-services

This command should work on any EC2. Then if it uses the instance ID, it should discover it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the AWS CLI command you have to use.

```
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids 'curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id'
```

If you have Termination protection on you can disable it first from the command line and then use above command.

```
aws ec2-modify-instance-attribute --disable-api-termination false INSTANCEID
```

Comment: bare in mind that the instance need to have the termination protection off

Comment: Can I use it to self terminate it?

Comment: Self terminate? Means what you want to do?

Comment: I'm using EC2. I write the script on EC2 and it terminates.

Comment: You can create a bash script sh file. And then run that file when ever you want to terminate that instance.

Comment: and how do I get the id from the EC2?

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: I think we are in the away. you understood that I want a one command to terminate it. but I get the error "You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure"

Comment: @VitorAbella after you install the AWS CLI, just set the following 4 settings (Access key, secret key, region and output format) - see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) it only takes a minute. Then the AWS CLI is ready to go and the line of code in the answer will work! Very cool

Comment: @error2007s are you able to explain ***why*** `aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids 'curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id'` works? What is the IP address in the curl request?

Answer (score 1):

you can curl the metadata of the instace to get the instanceId of itselff:

```
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
```

PS:
bare in mind that the instance need to have the termination protection off

Comment: I did the aws configure but I got the error "An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the TerminateInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation."