# What exactly does http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id provide?

Tags: amazon-ec2

The instance-id returned from a curl request to `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` appears to be the EC2 instance ID that runs that particular curl request [in this case, to terminate that particular instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453874/5783745).

Will this always be the case - i.e. is `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` a reliable way of quickly/easily retrieving the instance-id, or is there more to it? (I'm slightly suspicious of the use of 'latest' in the url - and want to check that this curl request is doing ***exactly*** as I think it does - returning the instance-id of the EC2 from which the curl request originates, and not something different, like the 'latest' instance launched in that group etc)

Comment: You might want to read [this AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-categories)

Comment: The `latest` portion refers to potential changes to the format of the response. It is possible to request a particular version of the `meta-data` response, to provide backwards compatibility. Specifying `latest` will use the latest version of the `meta-data` response format. It should be perfectly fine for your use-case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From official EC2 document [Instance Metadata and User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)

> Instance metadata is data about your instance that you can use to configure or manage the running instance.
>
> The IP address 169.254.169.254 is a link-local address and is valid only from the instance.

And from Examples of Retrieving Instance Metadata section

```
[ec2-user ~]$ curl http://169.254.169.254/
1.0
2007-01-19
2007-03-01
...
2016-06-30
2016-09-02
latest
```

I think it's the one you want, as far as I understand **exactly** exactly.